# How to use webfont data stored in Blob

Tags: javascript, css, web, blob, font-face

My website allows uploading custom font and changing properties of a text and its css through a newbie-friendly interface: only webfont type (woff/woff2/eot...) are allowed. The css above has a @font-face rule which must link to the uploaded file because i want the text to be written in the user font but i don't know how to do it: i tried using the url of the Blob but nothing happened so, do you have you any suggestion?

[PS: i have no server/php but only pure javascript because i'm asked for a temporary upload]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Get `.woff` file

2) Read it as dataUrl and store it

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(woffFile);
reader.onloadend = function () {
   woffData = reader.result;
}
```

3) Add style in html

```
var newStyle = document.createElement('style');
newStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode("\
  @font-face {\
        font-family: " + fontName + ";\
        src: url('" + woffData + "');\
  }\
  "));
document.head.appendChild(newStyle);
```